# How to restrict file size while writing to text file from an Android app

Tags: android

My `Android` `App` continiously writing logs in a `.txt` file. I want to restrict this file size.ie, if file size exceeds `1MB` it will not write any more log and notification will be sent to the user that no more space in your log file.How can I implement that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this code for calculating size:

```
File file = new File("text.txt");
                long filesize = file.length();
                long filesizeInKB = filesize / 1024;
                long filesizeinMB=filesizeInKB/1024;
```